# Can't access an element by a data- attribute with an underscore

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Good day everyone!

I have an element

```
<tbody class="cp-ads-list__table-item _sas-offers-table__item cp-ads-list__table- item_state-deposit" data-card_id="16676514">
```

I'd like to access it by the data-card_id tag, but when I try the following

```
@browser.tbody(:data_card_id => "16676514").hover
```

I get an error

```
unable to locate element, using {:data_card_id=>"16676514", :tag_name=>"tbody"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

I guess my code would have worked if the tag were "data-card-id", but it's "data-card_id".
How do I access my element by this attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

You are right that the problem is the underscore in the data attribute. As seen in the [ElementLocator](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb#L371-L385), when building the XPath expression, all underscores are converted to dashes (in the else part of the statement):

```
def lhs_for(key)
  case key
  when :text, 'text'
    'normalize-space()'
  when :href
    # TODO: change this behaviour?
    'normalize-space(@href)'
  when :type
    # type attributes can be upper case - downcase them
    # https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/72
    XpathSupport.downcase('@type')
  else
    "@#{key.to_s.gsub("_", "-")}"
  end
end
```

**Solution - One-Off**

If this is the only data attribute that is using underscores (rather than dashes), I would probably manually build the XPath or CSS expression.

```
@browser.tbody(:css => '[data-card_id="16676514"]').hover
```

**Solution - Monkey Patch**

If using underscores is a standard on the website, I would probably consider monkey patching the lhs_for method. You could monkey patch the method so that you only change the first underscore for data attributes:

```
module Watir
  class ElementLocator
    def lhs_for(key)
      puts 'hi'
      case key
      when :text, 'text'
        'normalize-space()'
      when :href
        # TODO: change this behaviour?
        'normalize-space(@href)'
      when :type
        # type attributes can be upper case - downcase them
        # https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/72
        XpathSupport.downcase('@type')
      else
        if key.to_s.start_with?('data')
          "@#{key.to_s.sub("_", "-")}"
        else
          "@#{key.to_s.gsub("_", "-")}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This would then allow your original code to work:

```
@browser.tbody(:data_card_id => "16676514").hover
```